# IE only JavaScript error Object.prototype and getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Object.prototype.size = function(){
    return this.length;
};

window.onload = function(){     
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

    alert(links.size());
};
</script>

<a href="#">test1</a>
<a href="#">test2</a>
<a href="#">test3</a>
<a href="#">test4</a>
```

It works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. But in IE it doesn't work. Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968416/ie-javascript-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-within-jquer

Answer (score 1):

In IE8-, `links instanceof Object` returns `false`. In IE9, this works fine.

This means that `.size` is not available on `links`. You should extend `HTMLCollection` because that's what `getElementsByTagName` returns in IE8-. Note that this again does not work in other browsers (IE9, Chrome, etc.) because they use `NodeList`.

You should basically not extend host objects, but this works on IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/wss6K/4/.

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.size = function(){
    return this.length;
};
```

In IE7, `links.constructor === undefined` so I don't think you can extend the prototype of `links` there.